# Tomcat error while starting the server?

Tags: tomcat

I'm having the following error while deploying my java dynamic web project on tomcat server.

> Could not publish server configuration for Tomcat v6.0 Server at localhost.
>       Multiple Contexts have a path of "/CRM".

Comment: You might want to provide some more context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete any old war files if present at deployment location.